# Angular2 how to change color of a disabled button

Tags: angular

i have this button

```
<button class="btn" [disabled]="true">
    <i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i> Like
</button>
```

I want it to be green when disabled but don't know how to do it

Comment: you can even use pure css `button.btn[disabled] {
    background: green;
}`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

component

```
isDisabled: boolean = true;
```

view

```
<button class="btn" [class.green]="isDisabled" [disabled]="isDisabled">
    <i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i> Like
</button>
```

css

```
.green {
 background-color: green;
}
```

another way is to add `ngStyle`

Answer (score 15):

With css

```
button:disabled {
   background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Well, actually this is the best way to deal with the case ;)

Comment: @JeanPaul A this could be most easy solution. Thanks for the same.

Answer (score 2):

[JeanPaul A's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45635971/3897578) inspired me:

I had a button with angular material properties, and a disabled condition. Something like:

```
<button mat-raised-button [disabled]="timeout==1"></button>
```

To change the colour of this button, I added below to CSS:

```
.mat-raised-button[disabled] {
   background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular 6. Switch delete button color from "warn" to grey

```css
.btn-delete:disabled{
    .icn-delete{
        color: #9D9D9C;
    }
}
```

```html
<button mat-icon-button class="btn-delete" [disabled]="array.length==0" (click)="removeAll()">
    <mat-icon aria-label="Icon-button with a delete icon" class="icn-delete" color="warn">delete_forever</mat-icon>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `[ngClass]` directive.

**TEMPLATE**

```
 <buttontype="submit" [disabled] = "!user.valid" [ngClass] = "{'my-color': !user.valid}">Submit</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.my-color{
 background-color: green;
}
```

or like this for your above condition

```
 <buttontype="submit" [disabled] = "!user.valid" [ngClass] = "{'my-color': isDisabled}">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it in 2 different ways.

1. Using the Class name and change CSS/SCSS
2. Using ngStyle

**HTML**

```
<h2>1st Way</h2>
<input type="text" name="value" [(ngModel)]="value">
<p> You entered {{value}}</p>
<button [class.btn]="value===''">Clear</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.btn{
    color: red;
}
```

---

**HTML**

```
<h2>2nd Way</h2>
<input type="text" name="value" [(ngModel)]="value">
<p> You entered {{value}}</p>
<button [ngStyle]="{'color':getColor()}">Clear</button>
```

**TS**

```
  value=""
  getColor(){    
    return this.value==='' ? 'red': 'green';
  }
```