# How to make button blur when button is disabled

Tags: html, css, angular, angular8

how make button blur when it is disabled.

Is there any way to do it?

```
<button (click)="addRow()" class="add-row-btn" mat-button [disabled]="isDisabled"> Add Row</button>
```

Comment: What do you mean by blur? Using `disabled` in the HTML button tag will make the button be disabled.

Comment: @funie200 blur means, before disable and after disable, button color is same. I want to make button color grey when it is disabled

Comment: @ashish I think this probably something you can solve with CSS or conditional classes  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45635845/angular2-how-to-change-color-of-a-disabled-button

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with css:

```css
button[disabled] {
  filter: blur(2px);
}
```

```html
Enabled button:
<button>Button</button>
<hr/>
Disabled button:
<button disabled="disabled">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Click Me!

```
button:disabled {
   background: #222;
   color: #fff;
   font-weight: 900;
   padding: 15px 30px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   filter: blur(2px);
}
```

Comment: how can i just make button background color grey? only background, nothing else

Comment: button:disabled {
   background: #d2d2d2;
}

just use this

Answer (score 0):

you can use the :disabled selector on the button class like the following:

HTML

```
 <button class="add-row-btn" disabled="disabled" onclick="addRow()"> Add Row</button>
```

CSS

```
.add-row-btn:disabled {
  background-color:orangered;
}
```

codepen https://codepen.io/ahamdan/pen/wvWKgqp